# What is this 'gerund' or 'noun'

Tags: grammar, gerunds

I read a book, and I noticed in it a sentence in which I do not understand what do the part of the language refer a word to?

A story plot is this: one man has busted the groups of people which are bug busters. Then another man says to him, "I saw your busting of the bug busters."
I'd like to know what is "busting" here. Is it a 'gerund' or a 'noun?' My reasoning says what is a gerund. In addition, it is a complement ("your busting") without preposition. Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the sentence:

1. I saw your busting of the bug busters.

We can make the following structural observations and analysis:

- The sentence's subject is *I*; the predicate is everything else after it.
- The sentence's finite/tensed verb is the transitive verb, *saw*; its direct object (DO) is everything else after it.
- The direct object comprises two Noun Phrases (NPs) connected to each other by the preposition *of*.
- The DO's first part is the NP *your busting*.
- The object of the preposition *of* is everything else after it, the NP *the bug buster*.
- The first NP in the DO comprises the possessive determiner *your* followed by the noun, *busting*.
- The second NP in the DO comprises the definite article *the* followed by the noun *bug* used attributively to restrict the final noun, *busters*.

The thing that guarantees that *busting* is a noun here not a verb is
that you have to use a preposition to connect it to another noun.

In contrast, if you could connect it directly without a preposition,
then the first would necessarily be a transitive verb with its own
direct object, as in:

2. I saw you busting the bug busters.

Now there is no preposition, so it is a verb in its non-finite *-ing*
inflection.  That non-finite verb's own direct object is *the bug
busters*.

There is also the possibility of using a bare infinitive phrase with
sense verbs like this:

3. I saw you bust the bug busters.

Here *bust* is a verb in a different non-finite form, that of the bare
infinitive.  This non-finite verb's own direct object is also *the
bug busters*.

Comment: So, the preposition 'of' makes it a noun, and without it 'busting' is a non-finite verb. Is my understanding correct?